# How to create new QImage using bits()

Tags: qt

```
img = new QImage(frameWidth, frameHeight, QImage::Format_RGB32);
img -> load(":/image1.jpg");
ptr = img -> bits();
destImg = new QImage(ptr, destFrameWidth, destFrameHeight, QImage::Format_RGB32);
```

I try to "copy" image using `bits()` so I expect two identical images, but there is an output
[image]

What's my problem? I know that there are different methods to do it, but in the future I will work with modifying bits so it's important method for me.

Comment: Do frameWidth/height and destFrameWidth/height differ? Note the implications on ownership and lifetime when pressing raw data. You might simply want to sign`destImg = img` and then modify destImg.

Comment: @FrankOsterfeld frameWidth/height and destFrameWidth/height are same values.
Ofc i can use `destimg = img` it's one of the solutions, thanks.